# Apache wont load certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7

When I have ssl enabled, apache fails to start with the following error:

```
SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

I have checked the certificate and it matches the key. I'm pretty sure the /etc/pki/tls/ folder has the correct permissions for apache to access the files. I'm at a loss as to what I'm missing..

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, it was in the ssl.conf. Apparently you need to have the certs for ssl in the global ssl.conf and not in a vhost.conf.